# Vuex store modules not loading in right order when importing store directly

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuex

I'm probably not seeing obvious, but after hours I don't get it still.

The problem: when I import my Vuex store into a non-component file (a api service), one module gets loaded properly while the other one only by name, but is otherwise empty.

```
// store.js
import * as collections from "./modules/collections";
import * as auth from "./modules/auth";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
    collections
  }
});
```

Both these modules are near-identical. Both have

```
export const getters = {}
export const actions = {}
export const mutations = {}
export const state = {}
```

Now when in some other non-component file I **DON'T** include the store, my vue store looks like this:

```
{"auth":{"authenticated":false,"authToken":"123","loginPending":false,"loginError":{}},"collections":{"collectionsPending":false,"collectionsError":null,"collections":[]}}
```

Now when I import the store to use it in my service like so:

```
import store from '../store'
// NO OTHER MENTIONS OF STORE, ONLY IMPORTING
```

Suddenly only my auth module is "empty"

```
{"auth":{},"collections":{"collectionsPending":false,"collectionsError":null,"collections":[]}}
```

It has something to do with module loading.

Order of loading by adding `console.log` statements:

- Without the import:

  ```
  INIT AUTH
  INIT collections
  INIT store
  ```
- With the import:

  ```
  INIT collections
  INIT store
  IMPORT STATEMENT -- INTO SERVICE
  INIT AUTH
  ```

I'm using the Vue Webpack Boilerplate

Comment: Are you using the service inside the `auth` module?

Comment: *when I import my Vuex store into a non-component file* When you don't, do you import it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, sorry. Circular dependency indeed. Was expecting a warning if I'd did that, but didn't.

Thanks Emile Bergeron.